# Cannot find or open the ntdll.pdb file

Tags: asp.net, debugging, dll, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

After the last windows Security Update (Oct 17, 2014) my MVC 5 solution (System.Web.Mvc) started misbehaving. I'm using VisualStudio 2013. Thanks to the help I received in here I fixed the problem according to the instructions found on [this page](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/10/16/microsoft-asp-net-mvc-security-update-broke-my-build.aspx) and [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26472017/the-type-or-namespace-name-viewpage-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace-system-we/26472110#26472110).

However another problem has emerged. Everytime I debug my solution I got the following message:

```
C:\Program Files\IIS Express\ntdll.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file.
C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file.
```

I searched for the dll but I couldn't find it. In an attempt to solve the problem I emptied the Symbole cache and I reloaded all symbols from the Microsoft Symbol Servers in a new folder that I've created with read and write permissions. The problem remained.

In fact it's not an error because I can still run the solution by clicking on Continue and the website works well eventhough the ntdll.pdb is not found. How can I overcome this problem and how can I recover the ntdll.pdb?

Thanks

Comment: I was able to turn off my antivirus to solve this using [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/127108/1751090). I am using the Qt IDE (with the msvs 32-bit 2010 compiler--it popped up with a window informing me that i should "use local symbol cache" and "use microfsoft symbol server" so I checked those options, and the box that read "do not ask again." Perhaps there is a setting in VS for you to do the same?

Answer (score 1):

I think your solution resides [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2015/01/05/understanding-symbol-files-and-visual-studio-s-symbol-settings.aspx), which is the "Understanding symbol files and Visual Studio’s symbol settings" page. It describes how to configure VS's settings for using symbol files/where they're stored.

Additionally, you can acquire system PDB's for multiple versions of windows [directly from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463028.aspx), this is useful for remote debugging scenarios (production environments, or those with multiple host operating systems which need to be debugged.)

Ideally you would want to set up your own symbol store(s) and configure visual studio accordingly.